# Why does this exception print as "list index out of range"?

Tags: python

I'm making a practice Wallet/money sending system, but for some reason, when `commands[3] or commands[4]` are out of range, it doesn't activate my if statement in the `except` statement. When I print `e`, it prints as `"list index out of range"`.

Why does `e` print as `"link index out of range"`, but when I run `if e == "link index out of range"` it returns `False`?

```
if command_keyword == "send":
        try:
            globals()[commands[2]].send_funds(globals()[commands[3]], int(commands[1]))
        except Exception as e:
            if e == 'list index out of range':
                print("'send' command requires three arguments. 'send [amount] [sender] [recipient]'")
```

Comment: Because the print statement calls the internal `__str__` function of the e object.  Try using `if str(e) == "link index out of range"` if that's what you want to do. But you really should break out the `IndexError` in a separate `except` block from other exceptions, rather than trying to interpret the error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the type of exception is `IndexError` and the information is an attribute of the exception. A better way to handle such exception is

```py
if command_keyword == "send":
        try:
            globals()[commands[2]].send_funds(globals()[commands[3]], int(commands[1]))
        except IndexError:
            print("'send' command requires three arguments. 'send [amount] [sender] [recipient]'")
```

However, if you really want to check the message instead, you can retrieve it through `e.args`

```py
if command_keyword == "send":
        try:
            globals()[commands[2]].send_funds(globals()[commands[3]], int(commands[1]))
        except Exception as e:
            if e.args[0] == 'list index out of range':
                print("'send' command requires three arguments. 'send [amount] [sender] [recipient]'")
```

However, note that this is not safe because not every exception has an argument and accessing `e.args[0]` may cause an `IndexError` itself.